# Zooms in obscure the whole screen

Tags: html, css, screen-resolution

My website has a header and when a user zooms in on my website, its header will also zoom in and potentially obscure the whole screen.
All other things are working well. My css code is:

```
#header {
    position: fixed;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 100
}
body {
  padding-left: 11em;
  font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman",
        Times, serif;
  color: purple;
  background-color: #d8da3d }
 sidebar { 
  width: 190px; 
  position: fixed; 
  margin-left: 410px; 
}
footer { background-color:Black; color: #fff; text-align: center; position:absolute; width:100%; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do with this:

```
#header {
  position: fixed
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
/* applies only if the screen is narrower than 500px */
  #header {
    position: static
  }
}
```